# Manually invalidating a composite layer in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, webkit, blink

### Background

I'm working on a web app built in HTML (not WebGL/Canvas) which includes 2d viewport controls for panning and zooming the page content. Something like Figma, perhaps, but rendered entirely with DOM, which is a hard technical requirement.

To achieve the viewport functionality I've made extensive use of CSS `transform` to power all offsets and animations in order to reduce the work required to render changes to compositing, as much as possible. The "canvas" of my app contains many discrete items which can be moved and resized by the user, similar to any typical OS window manager. These 'widgets' may contain their own scrollable content.

For example, after panning 50px,25px and zooming to 1.5x, the DOM and transform values might look like this for a particular "canvas" which has a widget at `(20, 100)`:

```html
<div id="canvas" style="transform: scale(1.5, 1.5) translate(50px, 25px)">
  <div id="widget-1" style="transform: translate(20px, 100px)" />
</div>
```

After a lot of experimentation I've discovered that the most efficient way to render these items  across multiple browsers is to promote each individual 'widget' to its own layer by applying `will-change: transform` to the outermost element. This results in a pretty reasonable framerate, even with a lot of content in the frame while panning and zooming.

### Webkit Misbehavior

However, there's one catch - on Webkit-based browsers, when zooming (which is applied via `scale` transform in CSS on the root canvas element), the contents of the widgets are not re-rasterized to accommodate the new scale value. At a zoom greater than `1x`, this produces noticeable blurriness. Images with text, in particular, are basically unreadable.

[image: A screenshot of two widgets at 1x zoom]

Above, one image widget and another DOM text widget at 1x (native) scale.

[image: A screenshot of two widgets at 2x zoom]

And now, at 2x scale (you won't be able to tell the difference inline in this post, but you can see it at full resolution). Notice that the image is just as illegible as before, and the text is blurry.

For a live reproduction of this problem, see [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/webkit-zoom-problem-rrdnp) (leave "Animation" unchecked).

> Side note: this only happens on Chrome, Safari, and Edge - so it seems like an artifact of Webkit's rendering behavior. Firefox actually scales everything quite nicely, and with a faster framerate to boot.

However, the performance of this approach is desirable. After trying some other configurations of layering, I decided the best approach would be to try to force the browser to re-rasterize the widgets once a zoom change animation was completed.

### The Hack

The intended goal is to allow the old rasterized textures to persist during the zoom animation to make it as smooth as possible (so the blurriness seen above will be present while the viewport scales up/down), but to trigger a re-rasterization at the final scale once the animation is complete - re-draw all the widgets, taking current scale into account so that their contents are sharp and legible even at 2x zoom.

To correct this problem, I have implemented what feels like a "hack": after the end of each zoom animation, I'm toggling the `will-change` on all the widgets from `transform` to `initial` for 1 frame, and then back again:

```
const rerasterize = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    element.style.willChange = 'initial';
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      element.style.willChange = 'transform';
    });
  });
};
```

This actually works. Now when I zoom in to 2x, the image text is legible and the DOM text is nice and sharp:

[image: A screenshot of two widgets, both legible and sharp]

(In my app, you can even see the moment when the zoom animation "settles" and text "pops" into high-resolution.)

However, if I understand correctly, the code above is actually forcing the browser to dispose of the composite layer for each widget for 1 frame, and then recreate it. While the performance seems acceptable in practice, I would much prefer to just ask the browser to invalidate the layer which it has already constructed.

### The Question

So, with all that context aside, the question is simply: is there a way to manually trigger an invalidation of a composite layer without trashing it? A magic CSS incantation, perhaps?

I'm also open to alternative approaches with respect to layer grouping which might improve behavior without harming render performance.

### Other Stuff I Tried

One thing I noticed when creating the [reproduction CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/webkit-zoom-problem-rrdnp) is that if I add a `transition` property to the "canvas" element (which is being transformed to achieve the viewport changes), even if widgets are composited in different layers, it appears to fix the blurriness. You can see this by checking "Animation" in the demo. However, my animations are currently done via JS, so adding a secondary CSS transition on top of this doesn't seem like a great plan.

I tried ripping out JS animations entirely and relying solely on `transition`, but surprisingly this did not seem to help. Panning and zooming felt noticeably choppier (some of this might come down to native easing feeling less natural than JS spring-based easing), but more concerningly the GPU memory usage and dropped frames were notably worse than without `transition` - which leads me to believe that `transition` might be causing a lot more work than I really want on the GPU for my use case (perhaps invalidating layers frequently during animations, when I would prefer them to remain intact until the transition ends).